# AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django

I got an error,
AttributeError at /ResultJSON/v1/results/
'list' object has no attribute 'id'      .

In views.py of ResultJSON(child app),I wrote

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from django.http import HttpResponse

def render_json_response(request, data, status=None):

    json_str = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
    callback = request.GET.get('callback')
    if not callback:
        callback = request.POST.get('callback')
    if callback:
        json_str = "%s(%s)" % (callback, json_str)
        response = HttpResponse(json_str, content_type='application/javascript; charset=UTF-8', status=status)
    else:
        response = HttpResponse(json_str, content_type='application/json; charset=UTF-8', status=status)
    return response

def UserResult(request):
    results = []
    results = OrderedDict([
    ('id',results.id),
    ('name', results.name),
    ])
    results.append(results)

    data = OrderedDict([ ('results', results) ])
    return render_json_response(request, data)
```

I really cannot understand why this error happen because my database(sqlite) has id column.

I wanna make the system that get datas(id&name which are columns' name and these datas are in my database) from database and encode these datas into JSON.

So,how can I fix this?I think  maybe models.py is wrong...(Because the child app's models.py has no code.)

Comment: `results = []` followed by `foo = ... results.id ...` looks very suspicious!

Answer (score 0):

Your `results` variable is a python list, the error you're seeing is normal as the list has no attribute named `id`

I think what you want to achieve is the following:

```
def UserResult(request):
    results = OrderedDict([
        ('id', x.id), ('name', x.name)
        for x in YourChildModel.objects.all()
    ])

    data = OrderedDict([ ('results', results) ])
    return render_json_response(request, data)
```

Better to follow [pep8 naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) as you're coding in Python that other people can easily understand what you're doing.

Comment: thx, ur comments.I didn't know Django's JsonResponse ,thx!!But I cannot understand that you wrote,you don't have to deal with content type and json dumping, so is it meaning render_json_response method useless?Where should I add these code? Would you add example codes which you mean ?

Comment: Forget about it, in you case as you're trying to append the callback it's not very useful, only when you have a plain python object which you want to return as it is. Let me know if your problem was fixed